# Is there a word for "collection of related elements"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm trying to use this word to describe elements like:

- Artist's (filmmaker, musician, writer) filmography/discography/corpus, collection of works
- Albums (collection of songs)
- Record label discography (collection of albums and songs)
- Small bookstores/libraries (collection of books)
- Galleries (a collection of artworks curated usually by style)

A word for curatorial collection is basically what I'm looking for. A collection more likely to be liked by the searcher through items that are related in style, tone, or aesthetic preference.

A collection of bits of information which are either related in style / in the same aesthetic world which are more likely to be taste-resonant as opposed to collections of unrelated items. Also it could just mean a "collection of related items" as opposed to whether or not they are likely to be taste-resonant.

Comment: You are looking for ***portfolio***.

Comment: It would be helpful in answering the question if you had some examples of terms you considered but ruled out, and other research you've done on the question.

Comment: Portfolio might not be the most appropriate I think since I think, and this answers Katherine's response as well, if I add more examples like:

 - Galleries (you find an artwork you like, you look through the artists CV and you find where that artwork was exhibited, then you look through that exhibition, and you find other artworks that are similar to that, that you are more likely to like.

Comment: Also, this is the beginning of my research for this question. I suppose I'm looking for a more refined/specific word than collection. A collection of bits of information that are more likely to be taste-resonant (liked by the searcher), than other unrelated collections. (Big websites like Spotify as a whole is an unrelated (less likely to be taste-resonant when explored in full) collection, but it contains related collections (more likely to be taste-resonant when explored in full)

Comment: How about a concatenation?

Comment: @rhetorician Concatenation is even closer! I might use that one. Adding it to my notes. Thank you. The last time I heard that word was in programming, so I don't know if people are aware of it outside of that world based on my very specific and relative experience (meaning unscientific analysis).

Comment: What about [Anthology](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/anthology) (*a collection of selected literary pieces or passages or works of art or music*)?

Comment: I think your answer is in the question - "themed collection" or "curated collection" -- are you trying to emphasize the fact that the collection is coherent, or that a person *made* the collection coherent?

Comment: @JohnFeltz  I'm trying to emphasize that the collection is coherent, not that a person made the collection coherent. But more than anything emphasize the fact that the elements in the collection are more likely to be liked by the viewer/listener based on the fact that they are similar. And you're right, I suppose I was looking for one word for that though. 

Graffito, Dan Bron mentioned it. I've added that to my notes. I didn't know it included works of art or music. I thought it was only for literary pieces.

Answer (score 1):

A [**compilation**](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/compilation) of the individual things you mention as examples might imply a bit more than “collection” that there is some logic behind their being grouped together.

> **compilation**   noun
>
> 1. [countable] a collection of items, especially pieces of music or writing, taken from different places and put together
>      Her latest
>      album is a compilation of all her best singles.
>      a compilation album

(from *oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com*)

Comment: Thank you! The more I think about how this refers to record labels, writing, and albums, the more it makes sense. It does seem like a more specific word. I suppose the idea that that word usually refers to music is what makes it a little uneven for me when applying this to a filmmakers filmography for me. But I suppose it could apply. It's definitely much closer than collection.

Comment: @YoussefAbdelmohsen The equivalent for literature is ***anthology***.

Answer (score 0):

Implicitly the items in a **collection** are related by virtue of being grouped into  a **named** entity so  "a collection of related items" seems somewhat tautological

I'd be tempted to use the term already mentioned - **a collection** ?

If the collection is **order-dependent** you could use a more specific term like **sequence** or **list**; if **duplicates are disallowed** you could use the term **set**.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah I had a feeling I could just call it a collection. However, I was looking for something more specific. I suppose collection could be used for items that are related. But I was looking for items that would be in a similar style or more likely to be liked by the person exploring that collection. Meaning, you find an artwork you like, and then you explore where that artwork was exhibited. You find galleries that have a collection of those artworks that are similar and more likely to be liked by you.